# The list of my favorites shows questions that are favorite by 0 users (and therefore they should not even be in my favorites list)

Tags: bug, bookmarks

Looking at the favorites Stack Exchange lists for my global account, I noticed the following questions.

> [image: screenshot]

For the first two questions, the number of users who added them to their favorites is 0. I wondered how that question should be one of my favorites, so I clicked on the question title to check this. The question page doesn't show I have clicked on the star, for the first two questions.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

The same happens for this question.

> [image: screenshot]

Even though I removed some of the favorite questions, there are still questions favorite from 0 users, after 5 (or more) hours I removed them. (I posted this question after I noticed what was happening.) As far I recall, I didn't remove from the favorite questions the "0 users" ones.

> [image]

I removed some favorites from the same sites of those shown with a 0. If I effectively removed those favorites without remembering it, there should be more questions showing a 0 in the first column.
I removed the questions from the favorite list by clicking on the question link and opening it in a new browser tab, clicked the star on the question page, closed the tab showing the question, and returned to the tab showing my favorites.

Comment: Possibly a race condition in how that information gets reported to the network profile. You did favorite the questions, but then unfavorited them within a second.

Comment: @animuson [tag:status-bugdesign]?

Comment: @animuson No, they were questions I added to favorites time ago, and those questions were listed in the last page.

Comment: I'm saying all of the ones showing as 0 users were ones you favorited and unfavorited at the same time.

Comment: @animuson I understood what you meant, but since I was looking at the list of my favorite questions, I could not favorite them and then remove them (since they were already in the favorite list).

Comment: To remove them from the favorite list, I opened the question link on a new tab, clicked the star on the question page to remove it, and closed the tab showing the question. Supposing I returned to the favorite list without remembering which question I removed, refreshed it to see the questions still to remove, there is still the fact that the favorite list updated itself by decreasing the number of users who favorite the question, but the question is still in my favorite list even after 5 hours I could have removed them.

Comment: The questions aren't duplicate, because the other user is saying he has never added the question to the favorites, except when trying to make it disappear by adding it and removing it from the favorites. I am saying there are questions listed in my favorites that shows 0 as number of users who added to their favorites, which means it should not be in my favorites, or the number should be  1.