# Question I didn't favorite shows up in my network profile list of favorite questions (but not in site account's list)

Tags: bug, specific-question, bookmarks, network-profile

I have [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) as top-voted among my favorite questions on my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/13311988/sanyash?tab=favorites):

[image]

But I didn't ever see this question until today, and I never marked it as favorite. And in my site profile, it doesn't show as my favorite:

[image]

Bug?

Comment: Hmmm, you did favorite and unfavorite it on April 19. Seems like maybe the favorites tab is not considering the fact that it was unfavorited. I seem to have a "favorite" from 2014 that I had undone the same day that still shows up.

Comment: So actually, I was wrong when I said "I never saw it"... Okay, but it was easy to forget :) (because I'm not interested in javascript)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315820/the-list-of-my-favorites-shows-questions-that-are-favorite-by-0-users-and-there

Comment: Yea, seems that this and related have the same reason.